# Change certain parts of the layout

Tags: views, panels, theming, 7

Iam using Omega 4 and Drupal 7 and Iam wondering how to apply layouts just to certain parts to the website.
My website almost stays the same, header and footer never changes, just the content area.
I created a subtheme and applied a layout to it using panels or context, just to try both.

So whenever I create a new layout for instance for the basic article node, I need to setup the entire page structure within that tpl file again, how do I avoid such things?

I took a look in the omega theme folder under template, and there they just put the specific thing they want to change in the files, and dont rebuild the entire page strcuture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution.
Just copy the entire templates folder of the omega base theme to your subtheme.
Within that folder, just edit or add new tpl files.
Those files will be injected to the specific block/content.